# Send Message to bot Framework Programmicaly using Vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, botframework, chatbot, web-chat

I want know how can send a message programically using javascript.
I used this script for load botframework:

```
(async function() {
    const res = await fetch("https://MYURLPRIVATE/api/directline/token", {
        "method": "GET"
    });
    const {
        token
    } = await res.json();
    var t;
    t = token;
    console.log(token);
    var styleOptions = {
        hideUploadButton: true,
        timestampFormat: 'absolute'
    };
    const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({
        dispatch
    }) => next => action => {
        return next(action);
    });
    window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
            token
        }),
        locale: 'it-IT',
        styleOptions
    }, document.getElementById('chatTranscript'));
    document.querySelector('#chatTranscript > *').focus();
})().catch(err => insertError(err))
```

I created a pastebin https://pastebin.com/FEYkNd8j with script shared before.

Then Bot Framework is loaded inside a **DIV** with *id chatTranscript*.

I have other button outside the div( id chatTranscript ) where (after click message from user) I want send message on bot framework.

I populate the input with a value "**hi**" and simulate a click using Jquery on right button.
The script work correct but the result is that the word hi is vanished on `input type="text"` and wasn't send on Bot Azure or/and not showed on bubble user.

Then where I wrong?
There is an example on your documentation in this path:"[BotFramework-WebChat\samples\04.api\d.post-activity-event](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/d.post-activity-event)" but I can't use this

```
script ReactDOM.render("<Composer directLine={directLine}><BasicWebChat /><SendHelpMessageButton /></Composer>,document.getElementById('chatTranscript')");
```

because I not have ReactJS on my server.

Please I can have some suggestions for send message using Javascript?
Thank you

Comment: A few questions. Are you unable to include the React scripts on your page in the same manner that they are on line 10 of the "post-activity-event" sample? Can you update your post to also include the code for your button since it is missing.

Answer (score 0):

While you can certainly simulate a click on the UI to initiate sending a message, the best practice would be to utilize Web Chat's functionality. In this case, on button click, it would get the value of the send box and pass the value into `store.dispatch()` to send the message from the client to the bot. Your code would look something like the below. This sample code is a basic implementation that you would want to spruce up. For instance, clearing the send box after the message is sent, don't send if the value is empty, etc.

```js
(async function() {
    const res = await fetch("https://MYURLPRIVATE/api/directline/token", {
        "method": "GET"
    });
    const {
        token
    } = await res.json();
    var t;
    t = token;
    console.log(token);
    var styleOptions = {
        hideUploadButton: true,
        timestampFormat: 'absolute'
    };
    const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({
        dispatch
    }) => next => action => {
        return next(action);
    });
    window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
            token
        }),
        locale: 'it-IT',
        styleOptions
    }, document.getElementById('chatTranscript'));
    document.querySelector('#chatTranscript > *').focus();
})().catch(err => insertError(err));

// Gets value of the send box
const sendBoxValue = document.getElementsByClassName( 'webchat__send-box-text-box' )[ 0 ].children[ 0 ].value;

// Sends the value as a new message
const btn = document.getElementById('otherButton');
btn.onclick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    store.dispatch( {
        type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_MESSAGE',
        payload: {
            text: sendBoxValue
        }
    } )
}
```